# Simple PyQt5 QPropertyAnimation not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qpropertyanimation

When the button is clicked, the frame is moved to the start value in the doAnimation function but does not move to the end value

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QFrame, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPropertyAnimation, QRect
import sys

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 680, 500)

        button = QPushButton("Start", self)
        button.clicked.connect(self.doAnimation)
        button.move(30, 30)

        self.frame = QFrame(self)
        self.frame.setFrameStyle(QFrame.Panel | QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setGeometry(150, 30, 100, 100)

        self.show()

    def doAnimation(self):
        anim = QPropertyAnimation(self.frame, b"geometry")
        anim.setDuration(5000)
        anim.setStartValue(QRect(0, 0, 100, 30))
        anim.setEndValue(QRect(250, 250, 100, 30))
        anim.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I tried adding print() to every line in the doAnimation function and expected to not print all of them. The output is that it printed all. What could be the problem?

```
def doAnimation(self):
    print("test")
    anim = QPropertyAnimation(self.frame, b"geometry")
    print("test")
    anim.setDuration(5000)
    print("test")
    anim.setStartValue(QRect(0, 0, 100, 30))
    print("test")
    anim.setEndValue(QRect(250, 250, 100, 30))
    print("test")
    anim.start()
    print("test")
```

Comment: It just gets garbage collected, since you're not creating any persistent reference. Either make it an instance attribute (`self.anim`) or add a parent in the constructor (`QPropertyAnimation(self.frame, b'geometry', self)`). In reality, you should probably do both.